# Is it possible to display:none text which is not in a tag?

Tags: css

I need to get rid of all the text in this div while preserving anything in <a>.

```
<div class="footer">
  Lorem ipsum etc etc etc... <img src="trash.png"> <img src="garbage.jpg">
  <a href="something.html">Somewhere</a>
  ... blah blah <em>blah</em> blah ...
  <a href="anotherlink.html>Another Link</a>
  ... in conclusion earthworms are interesting.
</div>
```

However when I use this:

```
.footer :not(a)
{
display: none;
}
```

the text still remains.

I can only use CSS for this, since it's a userstyle. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you can't select text nodes, one option would be to set the `font-size` of the parent element to `0`, and then re-specify a `font-size` for the `a` elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5L82c0we/)

```
.footer {
    font-size: 0;
}
.footer :not(a) {
    display: none;
}
.footer a {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```css
.footer {
    font-size: 0;
}
.footer :not(a) {
    display: none;
}
.footer a {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  Lorem ipsum etc etc etc... <img src="trash.png"/> <img src="garbage.jpg"/>
  <a href="something.html">Somewhere</a>
  ... text nodes.. text nodes <strong>text nodes</strong>
  <a href="anotherlink.html">Another Link</a>
  ... some other text node
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the down-side to this method, is that you will be unable to set the `font-size` of the `a` elements using relative `em` units.

---

As a side note, it's worth mentioning that you can also set the `visibility` of the parent `footer` element to `hidden`, and then set the `visibility` of the children `a` elements to `visible`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/gz4fj3yb/)

This clearly doesn't achieve the same effect as `display: none`/`display: block`, but nonetheless, I thought it would be worth pointing out.

```
.footer {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.footer a {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.footer {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.footer a {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  Lorem ipsum etc etc etc... <img src="trash.png"/> <img src="garbage.jpg"/>
  <a href="something.html">Somewhere</a>
  ... text nodes.. text nodes <strong>text nodes</strong>
  <a href="anotherlink.html">Another Link</a>
  ... some other text node
</div>
```

Comment: Good `thinking outside the box` -- +1

Comment: you can use font-size:16px;font-size:1rem; , the px rule becomes the fallback if rem not understood. beside, a thin horizontal margin to <a> would be usefull

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.show {
   display: block !important;
}

.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

and apply the show class to all a tags and hide to the div.

Comment: It won't work because you can't re-show something in a display:none'd element, and also I can't edit the HTML so this is kind of a moot point.